# Will a transistor latch remain latched when the input drive is removed? How to unlatch it?

Tags: transistors, latch

Below is a latch made up of two transistors:

[image]

When the base current of Q2 is increased this also increases the base current of Q1 which in turn increases the base current of Q2 more. By such positive feedback, both transistors go into saturation and establish an ON switch.

I have two questions regarding this latch:

1. When this latch is saturated by applying voltage at B1, what happens if B1 is left floating just after that. Will the switch remain saturated?
2. If the latch is ON i.e saturated, how can it be turned OFF indefinitely besides turning off the Vcc? Would grounding B1 work for that?

Comment: why don't you write the voltages into the schematic at all the nodes when external voltage is applied to B1 ..... then think about those voltages when you remove the external voltage ...... what happens to Q2 when you ground the base?

Comment: What happens ? If I knew would I ask? :)

Comment: @user164567 jsotola is telling you to do the calculations yourself. Which perhaps I should have also done, but it's too late now.

Comment: There is no calculation it is a conceptual question. It is just the topology there are no values.

Comment: what is the approximate voltage at B2 when you apply a voltage to B1?

Comment: I guess around 0.2V?

Answer (score 1):

1: Yes, it will remain on.

2: Short answer: You can't. Long answer: You *can*, but it's hard.

This is roughly equivalent to a thyristor, or SCR. There are ways to turn off a thyristor by drawing away current that would otherwise go to the base of Q2 and keep it on, but this is not exactly easy control circuitry to make because you need to route all of the load current through your control circuitry for a short time. And it needs to be all of it, or else the thyristor won't turn off. Shorting the base to ground is one way to do this, but whatever switch is used for that short needs to be rated for the appropriate amount of current, and have a low enough impedance to drop the base voltage almost all the way to zero. It's easier if you just apply a negative voltage to the base of Q2, but you still need high-current switches. Even higher current, in fact.

Note that I may have some details wrong here; it's been a while since I worked with thyristors that were designed to be turned off like this.

Comment: When there is no voltage at B1 and since there is positive feedback why doesn’t the leakage current Ico cause this latch to saturate? Thats a mystery for me.

Comment: It does, if there's sufficient voltage across the thyristor.

Comment: If there is any tiny Ico, the voltage can be anything theoretically if there is positive feedback. What do you mean by sufficient voltage?

Comment: What you indicate is avalanche effect but it is not about Ico to go increase due to positive feed back effect I was calling mysterious.

Comment: I mean under normal anode cathode voltage why doesn’t Ico cause saturation due to positive feedback when no gate voltage applied?

Comment: so how easy it is tu turn this latch off depends on RL, if it's relatively high like 1K to +5V it's fairly easy  to turn  off.

Comment: @user164567 base leakage

Comment: It's worth mentioning that building this out of just transistors like this will not work well and, as you said, base leakage will turn it on easily. If you add a resistor (10~100kΩ or so) between the base and emitter of each transistor it will work much better; those resistors will keep the transistors off before the device is gated on.

Comment: I wonder if the resistors connected in parallel to the base-emitter junctions are low resistive enough, this structure will become stable with S-shaped negative resistance... so that the whole circuit operates as an amplifier?

Comment: No, but if you add a resistor between the 2 bases, it will show a S-shaped negative resistance !

Answer (score 0):

It will stay on forever until you remove power by a switch in either location shown.

[image]